# Batch Script to stop Inner Loop when first instance of string is found

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, batch-processing, goto, findstr

I have a folder with a lot of sub-directories, each with a .diff file that I want to perform a search in for a specific string using a batch script. Because of our IT requirements, I do not have access to powershell. I am trying to exist my loop once my specific string is found in the file (can show up multiple times) and continue on to the next subdirectory. I have tried a few different things but none are giving me exactly what I am looking for.

The following script works a little bit, but restarts the outer loop all over again (keeps looking in the same sub-directories:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Set the path to the folder containing subdirectories
SET folderPath=%~dp0

REM Set the specific string to search for at the beginning of a line
SET "searchString"="COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT"

REM Set the next string to search for indicating the end of content to copy
SET "endString"="EXTRA DATA SKIPPED ON TEST FILE"

REM Set the path for the output file to save the result
SET "outputFile=%folderPath%ValidationSummary.csv"
SET "output_fail=%folderPath%Validation_Fail.out"

REM Initialize a variable to track whether the start search string is found
SET "startStringFound=0"

REM Clear output file for first run
ECHO Run Name, Status > "%outputFile%"
TYPE NUL > "%output_fail%"

REM Loop through each subdirectory in the specified folder
FOR /r "%folderPath%" %%f in (*.diff) do (
    REM Initialize variables
    set "found=0"
    set "copying=0"
    set "matchingLine=0"

    REM Read each line from the file and process content between searchString and endString
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /l /b /c:" COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT" "%%f"') do (
            set "matchingLine=%%a"
        set "found=1"
        set "copying=1"
        echo %%~nxf, Failed >> "%outputFile%"
        goto :continueSearch
        )
    if !found! equ 0 (
    echo %%~nxf, Passed >> "%outputFile%"
    ) else (
    continueSearch
    )
)
```

The following script will work, but it finds the search string each time it shows up in the file, but I want to keep the line number of the first instance and this will overwrite that:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Set the path to the folder containing subdirectories
SET folderPath=%~dp0

REM Set the specific string to search for at the beginning of a line
SET "searchString"="COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT"

REM Set the next string to search for indicating the end of content to copy
SET "endString"="EXTRA DATA SKIPPED ON TEST FILE"

REM Set the path for the output file to save the result
SET "outputFile=%folderPath%ValidationSummary.csv"
SET "output_fail=%folderPath%Validation_Fail.out"

REM Initialize a variable to track whether the start search string is found
SET "startStringFound=0"

REM Clear output file for first run
ECHO Run Name, Status > "%outputFile%"
TYPE NUL > "%output_fail%"

REM Loop through each subdirectory in the specified folder
FOR /r "%folderPath%" %%f in (*.diff) do (
    REM Initialize variables
    set "found=0"
    set "copying=0"
    set "matchingLine=0"

    REM Read each line from the file and process content between searchString and endString
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /l /b /c:" COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT" "%%f"') do (
            set "matchingLine=%%a"
        set "found=1"
        set "copying=1"
        echo %%~nxf, Failed >> "%outputFile%"
        )
    if !found! equ 0 (
    echo %%~nxf, Passed >> "%outputFile%"
    )
)
```

The following script stops all loops the first time the string is found (so doesn't continue searching remaining subdirectories).

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Set the path to the folder containing subdirectories
SET folderPath=%~dp0

REM Set the specific string to search for at the beginning of a line
SET "searchString"="COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT"

REM Set the next string to search for indicating the end of content to copy
SET "endString"="EXTRA DATA SKIPPED ON TEST FILE"

REM Set the path for the output file to save the result
SET "outputFile=%folderPath%ValidationSummary.csv"
SET "output_fail=%folderPath%Validation_Fail.out"

REM Initialize a variable to track whether the start search string is found
SET "startStringFound=0"

REM Clear output file for first run
ECHO Run Name, Status > "%outputFile%"
TYPE NUL > "%output_fail%"

REM Loop through each subdirectory in the specified folder
FOR /r "%folderPath%" %%f in (*.diff) do (
    REM Initialize variables
    set "found=0"
    set "copying=0"
    set "matchingLine=0"

    REM Read each line from the file and process content between searchString and endString
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /l /b /c:" COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT" "%%f"') do (
            set "matchingLine=%%a"
        set "found=1"
        set "copying=1"
        echo %%~nxf, Failed >> "%outputFile%"
        goto:ExitLoop
        )
    :ExitLoop
    if !found! equ 0 (
    echo %%~nxf, Passed >> "%outputFile%"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use labels within a code block/loop - it tends to do very unintuitive things like ignoring following commands etc. And you can't use `goto` to jump within a code block/loop. Every `goto` breaks the loop(s) (all of them), which in turn will invalidate the following code, if it refers to any metavariables `%%?`)

Your inner loop then could look like:

```
    set "matchingLine="
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /l /b /c:" COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT" "%%f"') do (
        if not defined matchingLine set "matchingLine=%%a"
    )
    if defined matchingLine (
       echo %%~nxf, Failed >> "%outputFile%"
    ) else (
       echo %%~nxf, Passed >> "%outputFile%"
    )
```

When you don't need the actual found line (you don't ever use it in your question), you don't even need the inner `for` or any of your variables (which means, you don't even need delayed expansion in this part of your code:

```
FOR /r "%folderPath%" %%f in (*.diff) do (
    findstr /i /l /b /c:" COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT" "%%f" && (
      echo %%~nxf, Failed >> "%outputFile%"
    ) || (
      echo %%~nxf, Passed >> "%outputFile%"
    )
)
```

This second snippet doesn't actually search for "the first occurrence", but for "any occurrence", but it is still faster than processing each line on its own (`findstr` is incredibly efficient).

Comment: In the first code, I believe `if not defined matchingLine ` is redundant in the `for` loop, since `%%a` can never be empty at this point.

Comment: @Magoo: OP wants to find "the first occurrence". `if defined` takes the first match and ignores further findings. (just in case it really matters, therefore my second code)

Comment: And this is the "inner loop". The `for` loop would not (re)set the variable if `findstr` doesn't find the string in the current file, potentially leaving a "false positive" from the previous file

Comment: Um - `matchingline` is set to *nothing* in the previous line so there can be no false positive. If the `findstr` locates the target string, `matchingline` will be set to *something*. It does not matter whether there is more than one match, so the test is not required. Your second code uses that fact, operating on 0-found else notfound.

Comment: except, OP needs that string later in the code (as the code in the question suggests), or removed some code for a "Minimal, Reproducible Example", so I took care of that possibility. If it is not needed, the second code clearly is cleaner, faster and easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @Stephan Thank you very much! The first code worked as I was hoping. I do need need the actual line of the first occurrence because I'm hoping to then echo out the content in that file to a consolidated output file but I haven't gotten that far yet in my script.

Comment: `echo %%~nxf, Failed with !matchingLine! >> "%outputFile%"` should take care of that (depends on your desired format of course)

Comment: @Stephan thank you for the response. I'm actually trying to catch the first instance so that I can copy between the first time I find it "matchingLine" to another place I am calling "endLine". Is this possible? I am trying to avoid labels in a subloop but I'm unsure of how to simplify it.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /nilbc:" COMPARE DIFFERENCE FOUND AT" "%%f"') do if not defined StartLine set "StartLine=%%a" & set "matchingLine=%%b"` gets you the line number and the line itself (don't forget to unset `StartLine` before). You can get the end line in a similar command. If you need more assistance about that, please ask a new question (this site is about "one problem per question").